# when did a codimension 2 manifold be intersection of two codimension 1 manifold?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Say let $M$ be an codimension 2 submanifold of $N$, when do we have $M=M_1\cap M_2$, s.t. $M_i$ are codimension 1 submanifold intersecting transversally?

My guess is if $M$ is a knot and $N=S^3$, this condition do not holds. do we have a characterization for this?

Comment: One necessary condition is that the normal bundle of $M$ in $N$ is a direct sum of line bundles.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese This should also be sufficient, by identifying the normal bundle with a neighborhood of M. Unless you want the $M_i$ to be closed, in which case the criteria are unlikely to be 'local'.